# Passing value Entry to value_sides in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Why value_sides does not have any value?. I planned to write number into entry_side and pass value to value_sides.

Don't mind order of widgets and also some of code was cut out to not clutter up the view.

```
class WindowFunctions:
    def __init__(self, root):
       self.root = root
       self.dice = Die()
       self.data = Entry(root)

    def taking(self):
       value_sides = WindowFunctions(self.root).entry_side.get() # Here is the problem 
       value_throw = 1000
       value_dies = 2

       self.dice.generate_sides (value_sides)
       result = self.dice.generate_results (value_throw, value_dies)
       frequencies = self.dice.generate_frequencies (result)

    def window(self):

    # ----Entry--------------------------

       entry_side = Entry (self.root)
       entry_side.pack()

       entry_throw = Entry (self.root)
       entry_throw.pack()

       entry_dice = Entry (self.root)
       entry_dice.pack()

    # ---Button-----------------------------------------

       button_generate = Button(self.root, text='Generate', command=WindowFunctions(self.root).taking)
       button_generate.pack()
```

EDIT: Here is file with root

```
root = Tk()
root.bind('<Escape>', quit)
die_function = WindowFunctions(root)
die_function.window()


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You have some indentation errors, please fix them

Comment: Without knowing what `root` is, or how this code is supposed to be indented this question is impossible to answer.

Comment: I'm sorry, just edited it